# How do I solve these Conceptual Dependency Problems?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Write the Conceptual Dependency Representation
of the following statements:

```
John shot Mary.
John threw a ball to Mary.
John saw Mary
John ate a frog.
John went to New York.
John sold his car to Bill.
John killed Mary.
John threw a ball to Mary.
John saw Mary.
The ball fell from the roof.
Mary knows that Clinton is president.
John flew to New York.
John gave Mary a book by handing it to her.
```

Can anyone help me out with the answers for this?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Can you show us your first attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either draw them as diagrams, or represent them in a Lisp-style bracketed expression. In general the first element is the semantic primitive used in CD theory, followed by the possible slots and fillers. How detailed you are with the specification on the PPs ("picture producers", ie noun groups) is up to you.

Here is an example for *John ate a frog*:

```
(ingest (actor (person (name John)))
        (object (animal frog)
        (tense past))
```

For subordinate clauses, you need a CD representation in the corresponding slot, as in *Mary knows that Clinton is president*:

```
(mloc (actor (person (name Mary))
      (con (is (actor (person (name Clinton)))
               (state (president)))))
```

In the embedded proposition, being president is not really a 'state', but I am not aware of any way to express roles like that in CD. The `mloc` basically means that the concept that Clinton is president is located in Mary's consciousness.